# How can I force require a non-exported file from an npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

You used to be able to do `require('library/a/b/c.js')` and it would just work.

But in newer node.js versions, there is an `exports` list in `package.json`. And if you try to require anything outside of those paths, you get error "`ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED`".

Is there a way to require those private files anyway?

(I don't need a lecture, please, just a solution)

Comment: You have a syntax error. You need: `require('./library/a/b/c.js')`. Works for me in Node 16.18.0. Doing it this way will just execute the whole file and is only useful for globals or side effects. You can't call functions.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen sweet! Leave a reply and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know where the package is installed, you can still `require('./node_modules/library/a/b/c.js')`.

But you should then not expect stability: The `library` might replace its use of library `./a/b/c.js` with use of another library `./d/e.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution like this.

1. Add file '`patch-module.js`' to project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/* eslint-disable no-console */

const libFs = require('fs/promises');
const libPath = require('path');

Promise.resolve()
  .then(main)
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack || err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

async function main() {
  const targetFile = libPath.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/target_module/package.json');
  const txt = await libFs.readFile(targetFile, 'utf8');
  const pkg = JSON.parse(txt);
  delete pkg.exports;
  await libFs.writeFile(targetFile, JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2), 'utf8');
  console.log(`Patched: ${targetFile}`);
}
```

2. Add this to "`package.json`".

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./patch-module.js"
},
```

However, Heiko Theißen's answer is better.